# postgres fast check if attribute combination also exists in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I want to check if the same two attribute values exist in two different tables. If the combination from table_a is not existing in table_b it should be inserted into the select statement table. Right now I have the following query, which is working:

```
CREATE TABLE table_a (
attr_a integer,
attr_b text,
uuid character varying(200),
CONSTRAINT table_a_pkey PRIMARY KEY (uuid)
);

CREATE TABLE table_b (
attr_a integer,
attr_b text,
uuid character varying(200),
CONSTRAINT table_b_pkey PRIMARY KEY (uuid)
);


SELECT * FROM table_a
        WHERE (table_a.attr_a::text || table_a.attr_b::text) != ALL(SELECT (table_b.attr_a::text || table_b.attr_a::text) FROM table_b)
```

However, the execution time is pretty long. So I would like to ask if there is a faster solution to check for that.

Comment: Not performance related, but `(table_a.attr_a, table_a.attr_b) != all (select table_b.attr_a, table_b.attr_b ..)` would be more correct. And that could make use of an index on `(attr_a, attr_b)`. See if a `where not exists` query is faster.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes) and the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, verbose)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `where` clause uses a manipulation of `attr_a` (casting it to text and concatinating with `attr_b`), so the index can't be used. Instead of this concatination, why not try a straight-forward `exists` operator?

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_a a
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   table_b b
                   WHERE  a.attr_a = b.attr_a AND
                          b.attr_b = b.attr_b)
```